# How to share the set of models with other user?

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

I'm using QGIS LTR (3.22.5) and I'm working on set of models that automatize workflow in our company. The process is divided into different models, because in-between there are still some steps I can not script (like correcting topology and so on). The rough structure of the workflow can be seen here: [image: structure of models]

I used to save my models inside a project and then pass a project file to my collegues, so they can use the same models in roughly same 'environment'.

The problematic thing is that 2 last models, 'Basic Befund Drawing' and 'Basic sondage drawing' are repetitive parts of a bigger model - 2. Autodrawing Complete. Sadly, whenever I save it and try to open as a project model, the connection gets broken and I have to reset the boxes.
[image: error: missing part]

[image: broken link]

Is there any clever way of passing such a structure to others without a need of constant rebuilding on each new machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out manually putting array of model-files in model's directory on new user's PC is enough and doesn't break connection to nested models.